# PostgreSQL tables to SAS and back

Tags: postgresql, sas

How can I copy PostgreSQL tables to a csv file using the x command in SAS? Is there another command in SAS that will let me do this? Right now I have to manually run the psql command line and then import the resultant csv file into SAS. I would like to run this command in SAS so I can run it as part of a macro.

Comment: Do you have any SAS/ACCESS licenses, particularly ODBC or OLEDB or similar?  Or of course SAS/ACCESS to POSTGRESQL...  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/69039/HTML/default/viewer.htm#titlepage.htm

Comment: We do (we're partnered with SAS.) But our own partners may not be. In particular, other companies want access to our product, which we will grant, but everything they write is in postgreSQL/python. We do not support Python scripting, BTW.

Comment: These are always an issue of figuring out the command you need at the DOS line. Once you have that, using SAS to execute the command is trivial. So figuring out the command line is looking at the PSQL tool and seeing what it supports, not what SAS supports.

Comment: Most robust way (if you dont have ODBC or drivers) is probably to put it into a shell script (presuming Unix ...) and call that via an x command. Or generate a .sql-script and call that via `x /some/path/name/psql databasename -f /some/path/name/scriptname`

Comment: What is the problem here? Did you try running your psql command line in a SAS x command?

Comment: Yes. The command works fine on the command line. It just doesn't work with x command. Let me copy what works on the command line:  psql -d kyle -tA -c '\copy (SELECT * FROM "FoundationLayer".location_hierarchy ORDER BY id ASC) to test.csv CSV HEADER'

Comment: x 'psql -d kyle -tA -c \copy (SELECT * FROM "FoundationLayer".location_hierarchy ORDER BY id ASC) to test.csv CSV HEADER' OTOH, does _not_ work, for any permutation of single and double quotes that I have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving the part of the command line with double quotes in a separate variable and concatenate it within the `x` command without single quotes. If coming from other languages this variable assignment seems a bit weird as you are not enclosing the value with any quotes but it is valid in SAS:

```
%let sql =  SELECT * FROM "FoundationLayer".location_hierarchy ORDER BY id ASC; 

options xwait; 
x psql -d kyle -tA -c \copy (&sql) to test.csv CSV HEADER;
run;
```

---

Also, consider avoiding the use of double quotes for PostgreSQL tables (if you have such control) as it tends to interfere with application code since double quotes needs to be escaped in most languages.

In Postgres and I believe Oracle, double quotes preserves title cases where any straying from it like `foundationlayer` results in an error. However, had you originally created table in all lower cases, you can call `FoundationLayer` without error or need of double quotes as [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) mention:

> Key words and unquoted identifiers are case insensitive.